# Pygame having trouble with surface.blits method

Tags: pygame, screen, bit-blit

I got used to blit every image into the screen on a seperate line in Pygame but now I want to start using the `pygame.Surface.blits()` method.

According to the documentation, it draws many images into another and it accepts a blit_sequence parameter.

So here is what I've tried:

```
MyScreen.blits([img1, img2, img3], [(230, 598), (350, 598),(470, 598)])
```

This led to an error :
TypeError: an integer is required (got type list)

I also tried this :

```
MyScreen.blits([img1, (230, 598)], [img2, (350, 598)], [img3, (470, 598)])
```

This made the terminal throw another TypeError:
function takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)

I tried the same last example but with tuples but it didn't work.

### NOTE :

I've taken a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54261954/pygame-surface-blits-when-using-area-argument) in which a very similar problem was discussed and I realized that there's an issue with that method but that post is 2 years old until now, so aren't there any solutions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation for `blits`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blits) says that the syntax is

> blits(blit_sequence=(source, dest), ...), doreturn=1)

I am not sure if there is intentionally an opening parenthesis missing there, but it's easy to deduce that the required syntax is `blits(sequenceOfPairsOfSurfaceDestination)`, meaning that your second attempt is close, but missing the outer sequence, as you are simply trying to pass each of the elements of the sequence as parameter to the function.

So what you want is

```
surface.blits(((surface1, dest1), (surface2, dest2)))
```

Notice that we are only passing in one argument, which here is a tuple of tuples. If the amount of parentheses is confusing, feel free to break it up into separate variables until you can understand the individual elements.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! That missing opening parenthesis did really confuse me.